# Gradle не подключает JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, jdbc

Пытаюсь добавить зависимость [JDBC PostgreSQL 42.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.18) в проект. Мой `gradle.build`:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.example'
version '0.1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18' // добавляем зависимость
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.service.Main'
        )
    }
}
```

И добавил проверку в java-классе:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Комплиляция через `./gradlew build` проходит успешно, однако когда пытаюсь запустить jar-файл на выполнение, получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

При попытке посмотреть содержимое jar-файла получаю следующее:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/example/
com/example/service/
com/example/service/Main.class
file.txt
```

Я до этого не работал с Java и Gradle, но так понимаю, что моя зависимость, указанная в `build.gradle` должна загрузиться из репозитория Maven и автоматически добавиться в проект. Или же мне нужно самостоятельно скачивать зависимость, добавлять её в папку с проектом и указывать `classpath` при запуске jar-файла?

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы зависимость подключилась и заработала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вопроса нужно было в таску `jar` добавить раздел `from`, в котором будем добавлять зависимости в наш архив jar. При этом есть 2 важных момента:

- Если в `dependencies` мы используем *implementation*, то в секции `from` нужно указывать *compileClasspath*.
- Если же в `dependencies` мы подключаем как *compile*, то и в секции `from` нужно указывать *compile*

У меня же в одном месте использовалось *implementation*, а в другом - *compile*. Из-за этого в jar не включались нужным зависимости. После устранения проблемы итоговый gradle.build выглядит следующим образом:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.example'
version '0.4.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18' // Подключаем зависимость
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.service.Main'
    }

    from {
        // Добавляем в архив jar
        // compileClasspath - если в dependencies стоит implementation
        // compile - если в dependencies стоит compile
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

И тогда в jar-файле будут необходимые нам зависимости. Проверено на Gradle 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию таск `jar` не включает в архив зависимости, вам нужен таск `fatjar` (*толстый jar*) или таск `jar` с другими атрибутами.

Краткий [туториал здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar):

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.example.service.Main"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал разные варианты, но безуспешно. В мой архив jar зависимость не добавляется (а я так понимаю должна). На [странице зависимости](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.18) есть другие зависимости в разделах compile и runtime. По всей видимости их тоже нужно добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно приведённой конфигурации в собираемый jar'ник не включаются зависимости. Ты можешь использовать какой-нибудь плагин, чтобы изменить дефолтную сборку. Однако у тебя уже подключен плагин [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Этот плагин включает в себя [задачи](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) `distZip` и `distTar`, которые соберут архив, положив в него необходимые зависимости, твою библиотеку и скрипт (как bash-версию, так и bat), который умеет *правильно* запускать твоё приложение. Обе task'и запустятся при выполнении `gradle assemble` как зависимые (или `gradle build` для полного цикла с тестами). Ну и конечно их можно запустить напрямую `gradle distZip`.

Собранный архив (zip или tar) можно найти в папке `build/distibutions`.
Сами скрипты запуска внутри архивов будут лежать в папке `bin`.

Единственное, что тебе ещё надо будет его доконфигурировать, указав main-класс.

```
application {
    mainClass = 'com.example.service.Main'
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. А что означает "_правильно_ запускать твоё приложение"? Я думал в Java все собирают jar и просто его запускают как `java -jar Service.jar`

Comment: С указанием classpath и т.д.